# How do start running a class through a sperate class

Tags: java, class

Hello i am trying to make a program that solves algebraic problems and i have run into an issue. the issue is is that i can't run a class a through a different class here is my code

```
package practice;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Algeabram8 extends Nexttimesandsuch {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Amount of X's on left side:");
        int xsOnleftside = scan.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Amount of -X's on left side:");
        int negXsOnleftside = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Is there a second variable? Y or N");
    String SecondVariableYorNleft = scan.next();
if (SecondVariableYorNleft.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
    System.out.println("Amount of Y's on left side:");
        int ysOnleftside = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Amount of -Y's on left side:");
        int negysOnleftside = scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of X's on right side:");
        int xsOnrightside = scan.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Amount of -X's on right side:");
        int negXsOnrightside = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("is there a second variable on the right side? Y or N");
        String SecondVariableYorNright = scan.next();
if (SecondVariableYorNright.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
    System.out.println("Amount of Y's on right side:");
        int ysOnrightside = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Amount of -Y's on right side:");
        int negysOnrightside = scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of all positve numbers on left side:");
        double allpositivenumberscombinedleftside = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Sum of all negative numbers on left side(Do it in a positive fashion ex. -5 = 5 (0 if none)):");
        double allnegativenumberscombinedleftside = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Sum of all positve numbers on right side:");
        double allpositivenumberscombinedrightside = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Sum of all negative numbers on right side(Do it in a positive fashion ex. -5 = 5 (0 if none)):");
        double allnegativenumberscombinedrightside = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("input +,*,-,/ variables for left side? Y or N");
    String yOrN = scan.next();
    String timesandothers = scan.next(); 
    if (yOrN.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
    }
}

}
```

This is the code i want to run with the one above

```
package practice;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Nexttimesandsuch {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        int add;
        int multiply;
        int divide;
        int subtract;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many +,*,-,/ are there");
            int amountOfSlots = scan.nextInt();
    while(x <= amountOfSlots){
        System.out.println("What is it that you want to put on slot " + x + "(+,*,-,/):");
            String Whatdoyouwant = scan.next();
        if(Whatdoyouwant.equals("*"))
            multiply = 1; int multiplyslot = x;
            if(Whatdoyouwant.equals("+"))
                add = 1; int addslot = x;
                if(Whatdoyouwant.equals("-"))
                    subtract = 1; int subtractslot = x;
                    if(Whatdoyouwant.equals("/"))
                        divide = 1; int divideslot = x;
                        x++;
        }

    }

}
```

I have tried many things but i cant figure it out P.S please don't insult me for my bad naming of variables i'm just screwing around

Comment: You might want to make your question more specific. What exactly it is that doesn't work? Does it compile, run? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: It would not load and nothing would show up and thanks for the the 2 down votes m8s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the Nexttimesandsuch class's main method to something else or change the arguments, and make it static (it already is). Using `public static void main(String[] args)` in multiple classes is bad practice. Only use it in the class that should be run first. So, rewrite the method like this:

```
public class Nexttimesandsuch {

    public static void main() {
        // etc....
```

Then when you want to run that method from any class, just call the main method like this:

```
Nexttimesandsuch.main();
```

Then the program will perform whatever is within that `main()` method. If the Nexttimesandsuch class is in a different package than the class you want to call its method from, you will have to import Nexttimesandsuch into the class you want to call it from.